# How to range ScollView and Button in a row in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I wanna to place a **ScrollView** and **Button** in a row, but It doesn't work, neither **paddingLeft** or **width**.

Without the **Button** the **NaviScrollView** will fill the hole view even I had set the **width**; with the **Button** and the **Button** will fill the hole view. Why?

```
export class Home extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <View style={ styles.container }>
              <NaviScrollView data= { fakeData }/>
              <Button title="添加" color='gray' style={{right:0, width:20}}/>
          </View>
      );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        top: 20,
        height: 44
    },
})


class NaviScrollView extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                {
                this.props.data.map((item, index) =>
                <Button key={ index } title={ item.title } onPress={ () => this._buttonPressed(item.title + item.url)}
                        color = 'black'/>)
                }
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using style property : `flexDirection : 'row'` for View tag to organize childrens in a row or `flexDirection : 'column'` to organize childrens in a column.

I make a simple example base on your project. I didn't know its similar with your project or not but just take a look.

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
       <View style={ styles.container }>
          <ScrollView>
            <Text>ABC</Text>
            <Text>DEF</Text>
            <Text>GHI</Text>
            <Text>JKL</Text>
            <Text>NMO</Text>
          </ScrollView>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.press}>
            <Text>Press Me</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button : {
    width : 50,
    height : 50
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection : 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    top: 20,
    height: 44
  },
  press: {
    width: 150,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor : 'yellow'
  }
})
```

Comment: I replace **Button** with `<TouchableOpacity><Image/><TouchableOpacity> ` and add the **flexDirection**, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Are **fontSize** and **fontWeight** useless in **Button** ?

Comment: Every component have style supported itself,

Comment: you can check on document, example : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style